# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

This is my code and it shows that i can't set headers after they are already sent. I can't figure out where did i go wrong with my callbacks? Please help me.

```
function signupSequential(reqObj, callback) {
    let usersList = reqObj["users"];
    console.log(usersList);
    let starttime = new Date();
    let finalResults = [];
    function help(i, cb) {
        if (usersList.length == i) {
            cb(); return;
        }

        // lowercase login id and email id
        if (usersList[i]["Login ID"]) { usersList[i]["Login ID"] = usersList[i]["Login ID"].toLowerCase().trim(); }
        if (usersList[i]["Email"]) { usersList[i]["Email"] = usersList[i]["Email"].toLowerCase().trim(); }

        console.log("Signing up:", usersList[i]);
        importUser(usersList[i], reqObj, (result) => {
            console.log("Import user result:", result);
            if (Object.keys(result).length) {
                // remove extra information from user object
                try {
                    delete result.userDir;
                    delete result.hashId;
                    result["InitialPW"] = result.randomPassPhrase.split(result.loginid).join('').trim();
                    delete result.randomPassPhrase;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                    console.log("error removing extra information from created user object");
                }
            }
            finalResults.push(result);
            // "Asynchronous recursion".
            help(i + 1, cb);
        });
    }

    // Start the helper, with CB to call main callback
    help(0, function () { let endtime = new Date(); console.log("time taken:", ((endtime - starttime) / 1000), "secs"); callback({ result: true, message: finalResults }); return; });
}
```

This is where signupSequential is called from. It's showing errors in callbacks. Maybe signupSequential is sending callbacks twice. I cant understand how. Please help me understand this.

```
function doService(reqObj, callback) {
    company = null;

    APP_TEMPLATES_CACHE = {};
    EXISTING_EMAILS_CACHE = {};

    if (!validateRequest(reqObj)) {
        callback(CONSTANTS.FALSE_RESULT_OBJ);
        return;
    }

    loginAdmin(reqObj, function (resp) {
        if (!resp["result"]) {
            log.error("Admin authentication failed", reqObj.curr_admin, company, "Create users", "fail", reqObj.reqIP, reqObj.name, reqObj.loginid);
            callback(CONSTANTS.FALSE_RESULT_OBJ);
        } else {
            company = reqObj.company || resp.company;
            APP_PATH = CONSTANTS.COMPANIES_PATH + company + "/users/";
            APPT_PATH = CONSTANTS.COMPANIES_PATH + company + "/apptemplates/";
            TZ_PATH = CONSTANTS.COMPANIES_PATH + company + "/trustzones/";

            signupSequential(reqObj, callback);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to set HTTP headers at all.

Comment: How is `signupSequential` called?

Comment: @raina77ow I edited it, please check.

Comment: @Quentin I edited it, please check. It's showing errors because of callback being sent twice for same thing.

Comment: The code you added still has nothing to do with sending headers. I assume `doService` is not a controller though; would be great to see something that actually is able to mess with the response flow.